# (Almost Done) Python program that closes stream when below audio threshold

Tags: python, macos, audio

I have already made a program that prints the max amplitude or volume, then I made a program that only prints the volume when the threshold is above 2300, now I want to make a program that closes the stream when the threshold is **below** 2300 for 2 seconds, so not right after it but in 2 seconds **only** if the threshold hasn't raised again within 2 seconds. Here is what I have:

```
import pyaudio
import struct
import audioop
import time

INITIAL_THRESHOLD = 0.010
FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16 
SHORT_NORMALIZE = (1.0/32768.0)
CHANNELS = 2
RATE = 44100  
INPUT_BLOCK_TIME = 0.05
INPUT_FRAMES_PER_BLOCK = int(RATE*INPUT_BLOCK_TIME) 
OVERSENSITIVE = 15.0/INPUT_BLOCK_TIME                    
UNDERSENSITIVE = 120.0/INPUT_BLOCK_TIME 
MAX_BLOCKS = 0.15/INPUT_BLOCK_TIME


class TEST(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.pa = pyaudio.PyAudio()
        self.stream = self.open_mic_stream()
        self.tap_threshold = INITIAL_THRESHOLD
        self.noisycount = MAX_BLOCKS+1 
        self.quietcount = 0 
        self.errorcount = 0

    def stop(self):
        self.stream.close()

    def find_input_device(self):
        device_index = None            
        for i in range( self.pa.get_device_count() ):     
            devinfo = self.pa.get_device_info_by_index(i)   
            print( "Device %d: %s"%(i,devinfo["name"]) )

            for keyword in ["mic","input"]:
                if keyword in devinfo["name"].lower():
                    print( "Found an input: device %d - %s"%(i,devinfo["name"]) )
                    device_index = i
                    return device_index

        if device_index == None:
            print( "No preferred input found; using default input device." )

        return device_index

    def open_mic_stream( self ):
        device_index = self.find_input_device()

        stream = self.pa.open(   format = FORMAT,
                                 channels = CHANNELS,
                                 rate = RATE,
                                 input = True,
                                 input_device_index = device_index,
                                 frames_per_buffer = INPUT_FRAMES_PER_BLOCK)

        return stream


    def listen(self):
        try:
            chunk = self.stream.read(INPUT_FRAMES_PER_BLOCK)
        except IOError, e: 
            self.errorcount += 1
            print( "(%d) Error recording: %s"%(self.errorcount,e) )
            self.noisycount = 1
            return


        while True:
            mx = audioop.max(chunk, 2)
            if mx > 2300:               #print the volume level whenever the volume is above 2300
                    print(mx)

            elif mx < 2300:             #If the volume is below 2300:
                time.sleep(2)           #Wait two seconds
                if mx > 2300:           #If after two seconds the volume is back up, repeat
                    continue
                elif mx < 2300:         #If after two seconds the volume is still down, break the loop
                    break


        print("You're Done")
        self.stream.close()
        print("Stream Closed")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    tt = TEST()

    for i in range(1000):
        tt.listen()
```

All that does is either print the initial volume level, over and over forever, or it just closes the stream immediately. This depends on whether there is sound when I start the program or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**:

While the methods posted in my answer outline ways to break your loop, the real reason your program is not working, is not because of the loop, its because the portion of code where you actually read the audio input is not even in your loop.

You need to read the input stream each time around the loop otherwise you will just keep making a check against the value when when the listen method is called.

```
def listen(self):
    while True:
        try:
            chunk = self.stream.read(INPUT_FRAMES_PER_BLOCK)
        except IOError, e: 
            self.errorcount += 1
            print( "(%d) Error recording: %s"%(self.errorcount,e) )
            self.noisycount = 1
            return

        mx = audioop.max(chunk, 2)
        if mx > 2300:               #print the volume level whenever the volume is above 2300
                print(mx)

        elif mx < 2300:             #If the volume is below 2300:
            time.sleep(2)           #Wait two seconds
            if mx > 2300:           #If after two seconds the volume is back up, repeat
                continue
```

You need to listen during those two seconds, instead of passively waiting.

```
    start = -1
    while True:
        try:
            chunk = self.stream.read(INPUT_FRAMES_PER_BLOCK)
        except IOError, e: 
            self.errorcount += 1
            print( "(%d) Error recording: %s"%(self.errorcount,e) )
            self.noisycount = 1
            return
        mx = audioop.max(chunk, 2)
        if mx > 2300:               #print the volume level whenever the volume is above 2300
                print(mx)
                start = -1

        elif mx < 2300:             #If the volume is below 2300:
            if start < 0:           # INITIALIZE
                start = time.time()
            else:
                if time.time() - start >= 2: #Wait two seconds
                    break
```

Comment: You put `if start < 0:` before you defined start. It tole me it was `referenced before assignment`.

Comment: how should I define start?

Comment: @user3151828 sorry, thats my fault, I'll add an initialization

Comment: @user3151828 AHHHH I FIGURED IT OUT.  Check my answer, I made an edit.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you aren't updating `mx` while (or after) you `sleep`. You should set a variable for when you last got a big sound, and break/restart based on new samples

```
last_sound = time.time()                # time of last loud sound
while True:
    mx = audioop.max(chunk, 2)          # new sample
    if mx > 2300:
            print(mx)
            last_sound = time.time()    # reset the "timer" because we're loud
    else:                               # I changed this to else
        now = time.time()
        if now - last_sound >= 2:
            break                       # two seconds of silence!
        else:
            print(now-last_sound)       # this should count up to 2
```

Comment: Yours does the same thing for me :(

Comment: @user3151828, i updated with an extra print. can you show me what the output is?

Comment: If I am speaking while I start the program, its about a thousand of these: `17765`, which I know was the volume level when I started it. If I am not speaking: `You're Done` and then `Stream Closed`.

Comment: Sorry didn't know if you got that?

Comment: I'm sorry I don't know why it didn't work. Did the other answer work? (if you set `start` before the `while`)

Comment: I wouldn't be sure what to set it as. time.time(), or an integer. It seems like it can only be determined after I have used it which is confusing.